# JDBC uses my username as Schema

Tags: java, jdbc

I've been trying to connect my application with  a derby DB, containing the table ITEMS inside.

The problem is when I try to insert an element in this table. When I hit compile/run I get this error (among others):

```
 Schema 'DEVELOPER' does not exist
```

Developer is the username I use to manage this DB, and the schema is APP, but I noticed that when I try to change the username I give to the DriverManager.getConnection I get the same error, looking for a schema named as my username...

Is there a way to tell JDBC to look insite APP schema of the database?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be answered [here on the derby site](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html#About+Schema+Names).